# Vaadin 21: Nesting Scroller into VerticalLayout problem

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Given a `Composite` with 3 nested `VerticalLayout`s, with full height each
And a `Scroller` nested into the innermost `VerticalLayout`,
And the `Scroller` contains a fourth `VerticalLayout` with 20 `Button`s

When the `Composite` is rendered

Then I would expect that the outermost `VerticalLayout` is fully visible on screen
And the `VerticalLayout`s and the scroller are neatly nested
And the `Scroller` is as small as required so everything fits on screen
And it is not possible to scroll the outer `VerticalLayout`s at all (as long as the screen is large enough to hold 4 `VerticalLayout`s, a `Scroller`, and at least one `Button`

**But** the outermost `VerticalLayout` does not fit on screen
The `Scroller` allows scrolling through the `Button`s, but the last `Button` can only be seen when the 3 outer `VerticalLayout`s are scrolled (which is not supposed to happen).
Scrolling the 3 outer `VerticalLayout`s shows a weird overlap of the outer `VerticalLayout`s.

Initial State

[image: initial state]

After scrolling the `Scroller` to the bottom

[image: after scroller scrolling]

After scrolling the whole canvas to the bottom

[image: after canvas scrolling]

How do I achieve the desired nesting/scrolling behavior?

Here is my code

```
@Route("3_scrollerx")
public class ScrollerxView extends Composite<Component> {
    @Override
    protected Component initContent() {
        final VerticalLayout lvl1 = new VerticalLayout(new Label("lvl1"));
        final VerticalLayout lvl2 = new VerticalLayout(new Label("lvl2"));
        final VerticalLayout lvl3 = new VerticalLayout(new Label("lvl3"));
        final Scroller scroller = new Scroller();
        scroller.setContent(buildScrollerContent());
        scroller.setHeightFull();

        List.of(lvl1, lvl2, lvl3).forEach(layout -> {
            layout.setHeightFull();
            layout.getStyle().set("border", "1px solid");
        });
        scroller.getStyle().set("border", "1px solid");

        lvl1.add(lvl2);
        lvl2.add(lvl3);
        lvl3.add(scroller); // always weird
        return lvl1;
    }


    private VerticalLayout buildScrollerContent() {
        final var scrollerContent = new VerticalLayout();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            scrollerContent.add(new Button("Button " + i));
        }
        scrollerContent.setHeightFull();
        return scrollerContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: The labels inside the layouts are also reserving some space. Instead of setHeightFull, try expanding the nested layouts, so that they only take the remaining space, not 100% of the parent height.

Comment: there must be a misunderstanding: I was assuming `setHeightFull` (equivalent to `setHeight("100%")`) is always relative to the surrounding layout. Is that wrong? Also, if I use a `Button` with `setHeightFull()`instead of a `Scroller`, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dealt with this when first creating the main layouts of my Vaadin application. It is actually a styling concern of the flexbox layout, and not specific to Vaadin. The computed minimum height of the `VerticalLayout` objects is the height of their content. If you set the css `min-height: 0` on the vertical layouts it will allow them to be smaller than their content.

You can learn more here:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto
- [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size)

This kept cropping up as regressions for us as developers forgot to set that min height. VerticalLayout is convenient, but has a lot of theming and styling baked into it for displaying individually controls well. If you are looking for a reusable flexbox component for structuring pages, consider creating a new component.

```
@Tag("column-layout")
@CssImport("layouts.css")
public class ColumnLayout extends Div {
    public ColumnLayout(Component... components) {
        super(components);
    }
}
```

With this style:

```
column-layout {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 0;
}
```

Implemented in your example:

```
@Route("3_scrollerx")
public class ScrollerxView extends Composite<Component> {

    @Override
    protected Component initContent() {
        final ColumnLayout lvl1 = new ColumnLayout(new Label("lvl1"));
        final ColumnLayout lvl2 = new ColumnLayout(new Label("lvl2"));
        final ColumnLayout lvl3 = new ColumnLayout(new Label("lvl3"));

        VerticalLayout scrollerContent = buildScrollerContent();
        List.of(lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, scrollerContent).forEach(layout -> {
            layout.setHeightFull();
            layout.getStyle().set("border", "1px solid");
        });

        lvl1.add(lvl2);
        lvl2.add(lvl3);
        lvl3.add(scrollerContent);
        return lvl1;
    }


    private VerticalLayout buildScrollerContent() {
        final var scrollerContent = new VerticalLayout();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            scrollerContent.add(new Button("Button " + i));
        }
        scrollerContent.getStyle().set("overflow", "auto");
        return scrollerContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comprehensive explanation. It works as described.

Comment: You are right that this is a CSS issue and not limited to Vaadin. But having to set `min-height: 0` on all surrounding layouts just makes me think that there must be a better way.